# how to make an method return both an integer array and another integer

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, return-value, return-type

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int num = 6;
    int[] sticks = new int[num];
    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        sticks[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
    }
    recursion(sticks,num);
  }
  public static void recursion(int[] sticks,int num)
  {
  int min_num = findMin(sticks,num);
  int cut=0;
  for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        sticks[i] = sticks[i] - min_num;
        cut++;
    }
    int[] res = minArray(sticks,num);
    System.out.println(cut);
    int len = res.length;
    while(len != 0)
    {
    recursion(res,len);
    }
  }
public static int findMin(int[] arr,int size) 
{
   int minimum = arr[0];
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i] < minimum)
               {
               minimum = arr[i];
               }
         }
     return minimum;

 }
 public static int[] minArray(int[] arr, int size)
 {
     int count=0;
     int flag =0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    int[] new_array = new int[count];
    if(count != 0)
    {
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
        {
            new_array[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
            if(j > count)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }

    return new_array;
 }

 }
```

here from the minArray i would also like to pass the flag variable back to the recursion method so that i can check that as my base class

So What my program tries to do is 
enter 6 sticks length among the 6 sticks length we try to find the minimum length and subtract that length from all the remaining sticks which will ultimately lead to one or more sticks with minimum length become zero so i extract only the non zero elements and generate another array and repeat the same until all the sticks have exhausted. 
Meanwhile i m printing the number of sticks that is been cut by each minimum stick length.

so, 
if my input is 5 4 4 2 2 8

output is : 
6
4
2
1

Comment: Your question looks sloppy to me, so I just skimmed it. You want a method which returns an array to return an integer as well? Can you increase the length of the array to store the integer?

Comment: Why not return a null if the flag is not set. And for the base case check for the null.

Comment: @Is it possible to make the integer array in java to null.. Sorry i m a newbie it would be great if you would explain me further Thank you